# passing variables to a form using onclick

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

I'm new to javascript and am trying to start somewhat simple. Is it possible to create a function that contains a form object that can be populated by an onclick event?

Right now I have a page with 7 buttons, each button is a submit for a separate form, they all link to the same php file on the backside of my site where they are processed. I would like to somehow create one single form, possibly in a javascript function, that would accept variables from the buttons when clicked and then submit the form to my php script. it will technically function the same as it does now with 7 different forms, one for each button, but will hopefully cut back on the code.

This example is only how I logically thought it might work from a couple of weeks searching around the internet and gathering bits from here and there, but in reality it is far from functional.

example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function form_variables(opt1,opt2,opt3){

   <form name='mySelectionForm' action='form.php?action=form_action' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' name='number' value='" + opt1 + "' />
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + opt2 + "' />
    <input type='hidden' name='option' value='" + opt3 + "' id='options' />

    </form>;

  formObject.submit();
}
```

Then this would be populated by an onclick event like this.

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="form_variables('9','1','6');" title="submit_button1" value="Button 1" class="cssButton">My Selection</a>
```

Comment: Why are you using a link as a button? Just use a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sort of on the right track.  Rather than dynamically generating the form each time, your JavaScript could fill in the values of the hidden inputs and change the action of your form.  So given this in your HTML:

```
<form name="mySelectionForm" id="mySelectionForm" action="form.php?action=form_action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="number" value="" id="number" />
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="id" />
  <input type="hidden" name="option" value="" id="options" />
</form>
```

Your JavaScript could look like this:

```
function postForm(number, id, option, action) {
    var form = document.getElementById('mySelectionForm');
    form.setAttribute('action', 'form.php?action=' + action);
    document.getElementById('number').value = number;
    document.getElementById('id').value = id;
    document.getElementById('option').value = option;
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I was trying to do. I'm not sure I need the variable action because I always post the data to the same file. Would my onclick event still be used in the same manner?

Comment: Yes, if you don't need the action to be variable, that'd work fine.

Comment: This accomplished what I was trying to do, a neat and simple solution. I've been trying to append this as well. Two of my original forms had a 4th variable that was selected from a drop down list with 7 options. I've been trying to add that 4th variable into the form by using the document.getElementId('droplist').value = option; but it does not function. I think I'm missing a part, maybe I need to select the drop list, then grab it's value with another command? To complicate it even more, it seems like I might want an if there is no droplist then the 4th value becomes null and isn't submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Just make each link like this:

```
<a href="form.php?action=forum_action&id={ID}" class="cssButton">My Selection</a>
```

Replacing {ID} with a number.

Then in your PHP file, use:

```
<?php
switch($_GET['id']) {
    case 1:
        $var['number'] = 9;
        $var['id'] = 1;
        $var['option'] = 6;
        break;
    ...
}
?>
```

And so on for each case. This is a much better system, as it keeps your HTML tidy and removes the need for JavaScript.

Comment: I would not recommend this.  Something like a form post should not be replaced with an HTTP `GET` action.

Comment: Why not? It's just as easy to change form values as to change GET variables.

Comment: If you have a bunch of links on the page, a crawler would follow those links and cause side effects.  You should never introduce `GET` operations that cause side effects.

Comment: What "side effects"? Guest users shouldn't be able to cause any negative side effects. I know one guy tried to sue a search engine because their bot followed all of the "delete" links the guy had on his site, but aside from that...

Comment: `GET`s can also be cached, breaking the utility of using them to trigger actions.  Use `GET` for getting, `POST` for posting.

Comment: Not if it's a PHP file. All in all, your arguments against my answer are only really relevant if the programmer deliberately screws up.

Comment: Your PHP might *technically support* using `GET` in this way, but it's a perversion of HTTP.  See http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html#checklist for good guidelines on which is appropriate to use.

Answer (score 0):

Not to sure if i fully understand what you are trying to do. I think instead of making the form and submitting it every time you click one of your buttons can you just use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function form_variables(opt1,opt2,opt3){
        window.location('form.php?action=form_action&number='+opt1+'&id='+opt2+'&option='+opt3);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have 7 forms with 7 buttons and want to use scripting so that when one of the forms is submitted, you'll copy the values to another form then submit that. I don't see how that will "cut down on the code".

Seems to me like it is increasing the amount of code - forms don't need any scripting at all. You could just use one form with 7 submit buttons, then sort things out on the sever based on the button that was clicked.

#### Edit

If you use a single form with multiple submit buttons like:

```
<form action="form.php?action=form_action">
  <input name="foo" value="bar">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit 1" name="Submit 1">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit 2" name="Submit 2">
</form>
```

then when the first submit is clicked the server will get:

```
...?foo=bar&Submit+1=Submit+1
```

and when the second button is clicked it will get:

```
...?foo=bar&Submit+2=Submit+2
```

so: one form, multiple submit buttons, no script, the server knows which one was clicked.

Of course you may want to use scripting to enhance the UI, but it isn't needed for the underlying functionality.

Comment: As my original post states I'm just learning, I'm still working through the basics and trying to do so based on web reading. What I'm looking to do is have 7 buttons that post variables to a single form which then auto-submits. That way I won't have seven separate forms. They all post to the same php file which then works with the data.